# What is the term for when a person or company tries to avoid liability by not responding to legal proceedings or requests for information?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, legal-terms

For instance, let's say there is a law that requires social media companies to delete personal user account information upon request.

Hypothetically, to avoid openly defying the law that requires them to delete personal user account information upon request, a company may choose to simply ignore all incoming requests for deletion instead of issuing a statement that they will not comply with the law.

- Digital emails are not responded to, they claim to be unread
- Physical mails are not responded to, they claim to be undelivered
- Phone number is either non-existent or simply redirects to pre-recorded messages

What is the official term for this type of roundabout behavior?

Comment: With your agreement I will move this to the English SE. AFAIK there is no specific legal term and so this is a question about the English language.

Comment: @DaleM Surely, concern about this type of behavior has been raised in SOME legal case? What did they call it, then? Not asking for an exact match definition, but are there any legal terminology that even remotely relates to this?

Comment: Sure: recalcitrance, obstructiveness, uncooperative, wayward - there isn’t a specific legal term that covers all these near synonyms and and any and all of them could be used.

Comment: non-compliance is what you're looking for.  One cannot legally avoid liability via not answering one's mail.

Comment: Perhaps **stonewalling** see [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stonewall?q=stonewalling) and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stonewall).